# Flash builder: 4.5-1: Problem combination "Localazation compiler optons" + "Generated PHP webservice"

Tags: flash, service, locale, builder

I've created a GUI in Flash Builder 4.5-1 with localization (copylocal as admin, created the files, implemented in he GUI...) and all works fluid and very well

I now want to generate a PHP service from my DB and that also works ok.

When I try to run the application I get the error he doesn't find:
Unable to open 'c:\Program Files(x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\eclipse\plugins\com.adboe.flexbuilder.project.nl1_4.5.1.313231\nl\en_US nl_BE fr_BE de_DE\dcradSwcs\4.5\locale'

When I retrieve the compiler options (additional languages) it works without errors.

Do I need additional steps to be able to use "Locale" and "Services" combined?

I used to work with Flex Builder 3 and didn't have the issues....

=============================================================================

update, still having the issue, isn't there nobody out there? This is the error i get...

unable to open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.project.nl1_4.5.1.313231\nl\en_US de_DE nl_NL 
fr_FR\dcradSwcs\4.5\locale' XofferSales     Unknown Flex Problem

it happens from the moment I want to use localization + php services.... :'-(

Answer (score 0):

open 'c:\Program Files(x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\eclipse\plugins\com.adboe.flexbuilder.project.nl1_4.5.1.313231\nl\en_US nl_BE fr_BE de_DE\dcradSwcs\4.5\locale'

Make sure Program Files(x86) isn't being truncated to Progra~1.